# Extracting information using a cell reference in a file reference

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am using Microsoft Excel to draw data from multiple files on a server, however to get this data they are located on different sub files which is determined by a cell on my excel spreadsheet.

For example I have in my formula:

```
='http://website.com/Subfolder/C9/[Contents.xlsm]Contents'!$Y$123
```

I cant get the formula to recognise the cell reference in this case **C9**. This is located within the active sheet. If I replace this with the file name manually this works fine.

I have tried using Concatenate and using a macro but couldn't get it working.

Many thanks

Comment: Does linking a formula to a web URL `http://website.com/Subfolder` even work? I think this doesn't work as the file needs to be open when writing the formula. And since it cannot be opened in an URL it needs to be downloaded first (even if it is only temporarily) and then the formula would link to that temporary file and not to the web URL.

Comment: Yes it does without the cell reference and the address put in manually

Answer (score -1):

You can build a complete string from parts using `&` operator

**A1**: 100
**B1**: `="prefix" & A1 & "postfix"`

**B1 result**: `prefix100postfix`

Comment: Then they must use `indirect`

Comment: yes, indirect as SJR suggested would work. But I doubt that a web URL will work (not tested).

Comment: Would it be formatted like this if it would work? ='http://website.com/Subfolder/indirect(C9)/[Contents.xlsm]Contents'!$Y$123

Comment: I believe indirect only works when the other workbook is open

Comment: No, Indirect will need the complete link inside the inderct formula [as you can see here](https://exceljet.net/formula/dynamic-workbook-reference). Note that the other workbook **always** needs to be open if you want to use it in a formula for the first time. That is why I said that I think links to web URLs do not work in forumlas!